# Android - Can we still get content by HttpURLConnection if server's response code is 404

Tags: java, android, api, http, connection

I have an simple Android code to call api from a link:

```
class RetrieveDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            String email = linkText.getText().toString();
            // Get url from the Edittext

            try {
                URL url = new URL(linkText.getText().toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("RESPONSE_CODE", "doInBackground: " + statusCode);
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
        }
    }
```

For some sort of api link (please forgive me I cannot provide it), the JSON shows *beautifully* on browser, but in Logcat (the "Log.d" command above), the status shows 404 (which means Not Found !).
This leads me to a question about writing a client app that request data from server. Can a client app still get the data if the server repond with code 404 or 400 (Bad Request) or something **when the data still shows well on brower** ?

Update: I also saw some strange behaviour when calling an API. For example on this link:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos
```

The response on browser shows well, but the result shows on my emulator is like this:
[image]

I'm getting crazy now !

Comment: No. Not the requested page. But many servers send a default 404 page if the requested page is not found. So then you will get that.

Comment: is there any "workaround" solution for this ?